# Specific word for piecing two facts together

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This has been bothering me all day. I'm having that problem where a specific word just disappears from your vocabulary for whatever reason. Google is incredibly unhelpful.

The word is used when two specific pieces of information don't seem to add up, or you're not sure how to piece them together, and it's used in a context like this: "I'm not sure how to [x] this new information with what we already know."

Another use would be when someone says two different things that seem contradictory: "I don't know how to [x] his latest statement with his original speech or supposed goals."

Comment: I'd probably use **connect**: I'm not sure how to connect this new information with what we already know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not restricted to OP's *exact* intended sense of *find a perspective from which two apparently contradictory facts become mutually compatible,* but in practice the most likely term would be...

> *I don't know how to **reconcile** his latest statement with his original speech or supposed goals.*

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reconcile)

> **reconcile**
>    to find a way in which two situations or beliefs that are opposed to each other can agree and exist together

---

More informally / idiomatically, there's also (again, from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/square-sth-with-sth))...

> **square (sth) with sth**
>    to match or agree with something, or to think that one thing is acceptable together with another thing

Comment: Reconcile is exactly the word. Thank you!

Comment: +1. I was thinking of "accommodate" which certainly fits the intention, but *reconcile* is better.

Comment: Just a note: I frequently hear *rectify* used where *reconcile* is meant. They don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @Chappo: I think within the contexts under consideration, ***accommodate*** normally implies not only that *one* of the "facts, value judgements, perspectives" is much more firmly established than the other (it's the ***dominant*** position). It also usually implies that it's this "pre-established" perspective that will be modified in order for some new position to be compatible. A one-way street in terms of what shifts might be needed.